# logcat messages from my device missed some lines

Tags: android, logcat

Do we trust logcat message from devices? I found that logcat messages from my Sansung Galaxy S20 device missed some lines sometimes. Logcat worked fine on other Android devices I have. The missing lines from my device's logcat really gave me troubles and wrong information for my debugging. Note that I turned chatty off for my device, so it is not an Android chatty issue. Does anyone see the same issues for logcat?